# get third child element with simple_html_dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

```html
$html = '<tr>
    <td class="aa">SomeText</td>
    <td class="aa">text 2</td>
    <td class="aa" align="right">
      <font class="aa">text 3</font>
    </td>
    <td class="aa" align="center">
    </td>
    <td class="aa" align="right">text 4</td>
    <td class="aa" align="right">text 5</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="aa">SomeText</td>
    <td class="aa">text 2</td>
    <td class="aa" align="right">
      <font class="aa">text 3</font>
    </td>
    <td class="aa" align="center">
    </td>
    <td class="aa" align="right">text 4</td>
    <td class="aa" align="right">text 5</td>
</tr>';


$dom = str_get_html($html);

$tds = $dom -> find("td");

foreach($tds as $td){

    if ($td -> innertext == $search){
        echo $td -> next_sibling()  -> innertext;
    }
}
```

problem is that this returns text 2, i'm trying to get text 4

I also tried the code below:

```html
$dom = str_get_html($html);

$tds = $dom -> find('td', 0)->text();

foreach($tds as $td){

    if ($td -> innertext == $search){
         $td->innertext = '';   

    }
}

echo $tds;
```

in this case the variable $search doesn't seem to work

is there any way to do this with simple_html_dom?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you mean the third next sibling.

You got the first next sibling with:

```
$td->next_sibling()
```

So to get the third it's:

```
$td->next_sibling()->next_sibling()->next_sibling()
```